# Warning on an optional arg disapears if it is the only arg of the subroutine

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, compiler-flags

I have a strange problem: a warning on an optional parameter of a subroutine when compiling with optimization on. However, if that optional parameter is the only parameter of the subroutine, there is no warning. To illustrate, I have the sample code bellow, two small modules `test1` and `test2` in the same file t3.f90. `test1` define the subroutine `foo1` and `test2` define the subroutine `foo2`.  `foo1` has 2 parameters, one mandatory and one optional. `foo2` has only the optional parameter. The difference between `foo1` and `foo2` is the mandatory `arg` and the printing of that mandatory arg.

```
module test1

contains
    !
    subroutine foo1(a, t)
        integer, intent(in) :: a
        integer , dimension(:), intent(in out), optional :: t
        !
        print*, a! actually, do something with a
        if(present(t))then
            t = 1!.true.
        end if
    end subroutine foo1
    !
end module test1


module test2

contains
    !
    subroutine foo2(t)
        integer , dimension(:), intent(in out), optional :: t
        !
        if(present(t))then
            t = 1 !actually, 1 is replace by a function call
        end if
    end subroutine foo2
    !
end module test2
```

I put the code in the file t3.f90 and compile as follows

> > $gfortran -Wall -O1 -c t3.f90
> >     t3.f90: In function 'foo1':
> >     t3.f90:5:0: warning: 't.0' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
> >     subroutine foo1(a, t)

It is very strange that I do not have the same warning with `foo2`. If I remove the optimization flag, the warning goes away.

I am using gfortran 4.8.2. Is this a bug or my misunderstanding of something? If it is a bug, is it solved in newer version?

---

From the inputs of VladimirF and francescalus, I found it useful to add the following details for those who are familiar with the GCC internals.
If I change the name `t` to whatever name `xxx`, I get the same warning with `t.0` replaced by `xxx.0`. That is why I think that the warning is really related to my variable.

Comment: Without much investigating I can say I have seen several spurious `may be used uninitialized` warnings before. Notice the name of the variable is something internal to the compiler.

Comment: @VladimirF, In another case, I had such supurius with variable name that I did not recognize. I was thinking that it was just a displaced warning. This one is my own variable, the name changes in the warning when I change it in the code.

Comment: Note the `t.0` rather than `t`, which I assume Vladimir F was intimating as being the internal (possibly related to a dope vector associated with your variable named `t`, but I'm not familiar with gcc internals).

Comment: @francescalus, you are right! It is possibly part of the data structure that the compiler internally used to represent my variable. Just to add more input for those who are more familliar with the internals of GCC. if I change the name `t` to whatever name `xxx`, I get the same warning with `t.0` replaced by `xxx.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the gcc 4.8.2 (and possibly version bellow). I just get access to gcc 4.9.1 and the warning is not there for both cases.

Comment: I tested your code with Intel Fortran compilers (v13 and v15) and did not get any warnings. The problem may very well be with the version of gcc that you were using originally.